# How do I create a dynamic Component as a parameter - angular agGrid cellEditorFramework

Tags: angularjs, angular, ag-grid, angular-components

Not sure if it matters, but I am using agGrid, but it is basically creating a dynamic component as a parameter. This works fine as my GridOptions:

```
...
children: [
    ...
    cellEditorFramework: SelectCellComponent,
    ...
]
...
```

but what if I want to do a conditional editor?  Something like this:

```
...
children: [
    ...
    cellEditorFramework: (params) => {
        return params.type === 'Select' ? SelectCellComponent : TextCellComponent
    },
    ...
]
...
```

but that gives me the error:

> No component factory found for function (params) {. Did you add it to
>   @NgModule.entryComponents?

Is there a way to do this?

angular 4.4.6
agGrid 17.1.1

Answer (score -1):

You can create wrapping angular component

SelectOrTextWrapperComponent

```
...
children: [
    ...
    cellEditorFramework: SelectOrTextWrapperComponent,
    ...
]
...
```

And inside in runtime decide what to display - select or text

```
<select-cell *ngIf="params.type == 'select'"></select-cell>
<text-cell *ngIf="params.type != 'select'"></text-cell>
```

Comment: you are talking about a different thing, `cellEditorFramework` just a definition for `ag-grid` library, you can't use angular directive for that.

Comment: Looks like misunderstanding. You want to define component in runtime according to params. And it can be done inside framework component itself.

Comment: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-components/ .      

Component usage:

Name / Direct JavaScript: This can be: 1) A component name referring to a registered component (either plain JavaScript or framework component); 2) A direct reference to a JavaScript component.
Direct Framework: A direct **reference to a framework** (React, Angular etc) **component**.